# I can't link more than one word files to my pysimpleGUI program

Tags: python, excel, cpu-word, pysimplegui

I'm building an Word template generator for work using excel data to create bulk documents.
However I can at the moment choose only 1 template and I want to be able to use multiple ones.

I can write an if statement to change my word_template_path but I don't know how to do that when trying to embedded this code into pysimpleGUI.

```
# ----------Instructions for use function----------- #
def instructions():
    sg.popup_scrolled(f"HOW TO USE THE TEMPLATE GENERATOR "
                      f"\n 1.   Store the application and supporting folder directly on the Desktop. Otherwise, the program won’t work."
                      f"\n 2.   Populate the raw_data.xlsx with all relevant details you need, e.g. Legal entity name, address, VATid, Base and click charges, etc."
                      f"\n 3.   Ones you start the program, select test_template.docx in the Input File: field."
                      f"\n 4.   Then select raw_data.xlsx in the Excel Files: field."
                      f"\n 5.   Click on Generate Template ")

# ----------Main program function for creating multiple templates----------- #
def generate_word_template(word_template_path, excel_path, output_path):
    base_dir = Path.home() / "Desktop"
    word_template_path = base_dir / "test_template.docx"
    excel_path = base_dir / "data2.xlsx"
    output_dir = base_dir / "OUTPUT"

    output_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

    df = pd.read_excel(excel_path, sheet_name="Sheet3")

    for record in df.to_dict(orient="records"):
        doc = DocxTemplate(word_template_path)
        doc.render(record)
        output_path = output_dir / f"{record['SITECODE']}-HP Advance_CO"
        doc.save(output_path)
    sg.popup_no_titlebar("Done! :)")

# ----------GUI Definition. Program Window view----------- #
layout =[
    [sg.Text("Import Word Template:"), sg.Input(key="-IN-"), sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("Word Template", "*.doc*"),))],
    [sg.Text("Import Excel raw data:"), sg.Input(key="-IN-"), sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("Excel raw data", "*.xls*"),))],
    [sg.Text("Output Folder:"), sg.Input(key="-OUT-"), sg.FolderBrowse()],
    [sg.Exit(), sg.Button("Populate Template"), sg.Button("Instructions")],
]

window = sg.Window("Populate multiple Word templates", layout)

# ----------Closing program and displaying error message----------- #
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED,"Exit"):
        break
    if event == "Instructions":
        instructions()
    if event == "Populate Template":
        generate_word_template(
            word_template_path=values["-IN-"],
            excel_path=values["-IN-"],
            output_path=values["-OUT-"]
        )


window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You Key for each pySimpleGui element must be unique. Every button the user press that you want to know, must have a key assigned to it.

Update your layout and main loop to:

```
# ----------GUI Definition. Program Window view----------- #
layout = [[sg.Text("Import Word Template:"), sg.Input(key="-Template-"),
           sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("Word Template", "*.doc*"),))],
          [sg.Text("Import Excel raw data:"), sg.Input(key="-Raw-"),
           sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("Excel raw data", "*.xls*"),))],
          [sg.Text("Output Folder:"), sg.Input(key="-OUT-"), sg.FolderBrowse()],
          [sg.Exit(key="-Exit-"), sg.Button("Populate Template", key="-Populate Template-"),
           sg.Button("Instructions", key="-Instructions-")],
          ]
window = sg.Window("Populate multiple Word templates", layout)

# ----------Closing program and displaying error message----------- #
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED,"-Exit-"):
        break
    if event == "-Instructions-":
        print("User asked for Instructions.  Running instructions function")
        #instructions()
    if event == "-Populate Template-":
        print(f"running command: generate_word_template(
                {values['-Template-']},
                {values['-Raw-']},
                {values['-OUT-']})")
        # generate_word_template(
        #     word_template_path=values["-Template-"],
        #     excel_path=values["-Raw-"],
        #     output_path=values["-OUT-"]
        #)
window.close()
```